# Fetch xml tag values recursively using ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an xmk of the type:

```
<SCHOOL>
    <GROUP name="GetStudInfo">

        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Sahil Jha</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>

        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Rashmi Kaur</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>

        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Palak Bisht</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>
</SCHOOL>
```

I need to fetch the values of NAME, STD.
I tried doing this:

```
e = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(getunitinfo_str))
    for elt in e.iter():
        print("{} {}".format(elt.tag, elt.text))
```

But this was covering other values as well:
Output:

```
SCHOOL

GROUP


DATA

NAME Sahil Jha
STD 11th
DATA

NAME Rashmi Kaur
STD 11th
DATA

NAME Palak Bisht
STD 11th
{}
```

Expected O/p:

```
{'Sahil Jha':'11th', 'Rashmi Kaur'::'11th', 'Palak Bisht':'11th'}
```

But the formatting should be of the type `NAME:STD`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you give the expected output?

Comment: @qouify I have added the expected result.

Comment: maybe you should use `xpath` to get it - first `xpath("//DATA")` to get all `<DATA>` and later in every data use (relative xpath with dot) `xpath(".//NAME")` and `xpath("//STD")`

Comment: if you want expected output then you have to write someting more then `print()` - you should use `if/else` to check elt.tag and keep only `NAME` and `STD` and then get `elt.text`. But they will be in two separated loop so you have keep `NAME` in variable and when you get `NAME` then create pair `NAME:STD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned by @furas you can use XPATH to find all `DATA` elements and then find
`NAME` and `STD` elements:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<SCHOOL>
    <GROUP name="GetStudInfo">

        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Sahil Jha</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>

        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Rashmi Kaur</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>

        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Palak Bisht</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>
</GROUP>
</SCHOOL>'''


e = ET.fromstring(xml)
for data_tag in e.findall('DATA'):
    name = data_tag.find('NAME')
    std = data_tag.find('STD')
    print("{} {}".format(name.text, std.text))
```

Or you can use a dict comprehension to get the dictionary you want:

```py
my_dict = {
    data_tag.find('NAME').text: data_tag.find('STD').text
    for data_tag in e.findall('.//DATA')
}
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something more then only `print()` - you need `if/else` to check `elt.tag` to get only `NAME` and `STD.

Because `NAME` and `STD` are different tags so you will have to remeber `NAME` in some variable to use it when you get `STD`

```py
name = None  # default value at start

for elt in e.iter():
    if elt.tag == 'NAME':
        name = elt  # remember element
    if elt.tag == 'STD':
        print("{}:{}".format(name.text, elt.text))
```

Or you could use `xpath` like in @qouify answer.

---

Minimal working code

```py
getunitinfo_str = '''
<SCHOOL>
    <GROUP name="GetStudInfo">

        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Sahil Jha</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>

        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Rashmi Kaur</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>

        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Palak Bisht</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>
    </GROUP>
</SCHOOL>
'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree  as ET

e = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(getunitinfo_str))

name = None # to remeber element

for elt in e.iter():
    if elt.tag == 'NAME':
        name = elt
    if elt.tag == 'STD':
       print("{}:{}".format(name.text, elt.text))
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<SCHOOL>
    <GROUP name="GetStudInfo">
        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Sahil Jha</NAME>
            <STD>11th</STD>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Rashmi Kaur</NAME>
            <STD>116th</STD>
        </DATA>
        <DATA>
            <NAME type="char">Palak Bisht</NAME>
            <STD>17th</STD>
        </DATA>
</GROUP>
</SCHOOL>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = {x.find("NAME").text: x.find("STD").text for x in root.findall('.//DATA')}
print(data)
```

output

```
{'Sahil Jha': '11th', 'Rashmi Kaur': '116th', 'Palak Bisht': '17th'}
```